# Websockets: Connection Refused, but both client and server work with other clients and servers

Tags: ios, swift, networking, websocket, client-server

I have a Java WebSocket API using [this](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki#server-example) library and a Swift iOS WebSocket client in my application using the [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) library. When I test my Java server with [WebSocketKing](https://websocketking.com/) it works perfectly. When I test my Swift iOS client with `ws://echo.websocket.org` as the host it also works perfectly. But when I try to connect my client to my server using host `localhost:5001` (or any other port like 8080) I get this error:

```
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

I can't find anything online that has helped me track down why my server and client can't talk to each other. There is no authentication going on yet. `nc -v localhost 5001` provides this message:

```
Connection to localhost port 5001 [tcp/commplex-link] succeeded!
```

So I officially have no idea wtf is going on lol. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just realized my mistake: I was using a physical device as the simulator, which was trying to connect to "localhost:5001", which doesn't exist for the iPhone's localhost. I'm going to have to host this websocket server on AWS or something to test it out.